# Find Code coverage of .Net solution from command line

Tags: .net

I want to find code coverage of c# .Net solution having Test projects. Right now we can get Test results and code coverage of solution by selecting Test -> Run -> All Tests. But I want to do it via command line.

Comment: It depends, Which Visual Studio Version, and which unit test framework (mstest, nunit, xunit, etc) are you using?

Comment: @JhonatanP thanks for comment , I already found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I used [VSTest.Console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) to perform task to find code coverage as below

```
VSTest.Console.exe test.dll /Enablecodecoverage
```